# Why this code doesn't return false?

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
function every(array, predictate){
    array.forEach(function(x){
    if (!predictate(x))
        {
        return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}


console.log(every([NaN, NaN, NaN], isNaN));
//true
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
//suppose to return false, but still return true...
```

The second `console.log` should return false but it returns true. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return false` is the return of the anonymous function used in the `forEach`. So it does not return anything for `every`. If you want to use `forEach` and return false, you have to do like this :

```
function every(array, predictate) {
    var result = true;

    array.forEach(function(x) {
        if (!predictate(x)) {
            result = false;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think i almost get it. Do you think you can clarify it a bit more?
"The return false is the return of the anonymous function used in the forEach."

You're referring to function(x)? Why it couldn't return false?

I'm sorry if i don't make any sense.

Comment: Yes i refer to `function(x)`. This function can return false, and that's what you are doing. But `every` will not return false just because the anonymous function return false.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean... because i'm calling every not the anonymous function that's why i want the every to return false not the anonymous function.

I've been going at this for a while. I finally got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return false` statement is for the `forEach` callback function, not for the external `every`.

`every` will always return true unless you change it to something like:

```
function every(array, predictate){
    var retValue = true;
    array.forEach(function(x){
    if (!predictate(x))
        {
        retValue = false;
        }
    });
    return retValue;
}
```